# std::make_unique and designated initializers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, designated-initializer

Consider this structure:

```cpp
struct MyStruct
{
  int my_number;
  std::string my_string;
};
```

Is it possible to create a `std::unique_ptr` using [Designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers)? Like this:

```cpp
// like this
auto my_struct = std::make_unique<MyStruct>{.my_number = 4, .my_string = "two"};
// not like this
auto my_struct = std::make_unique<MyStruct>(4, "two");
```

I've managed to create a new object as an argument to `unique_ptr`, but find it ugly:

```cpp
auto my_struct = std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>(new MyStruct{.my_number = 4, .my_string = "two"});
```

Comment: Nope, that's not possible, since `std::make_unique` is a function template. You could of course use the implicitly created move constructor here, but that doesn't seem much better than your last code snippet: `auto my_struct = std::make_unique<MyStruct>(MyStruct{.my_number = 4, .my_string = "two"});`

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to create a `std::unique_ptr` using Designated initializers?

**No**.  Unfortunately, you can’t even use CTAD to avoid the redundancy:

```
auto my_struct = std::unique_ptr(new MyStruct{.my_number = 4, .my_string = "two"});  // error: deduction failed
```

for fear of the argument being `new MyStruct[…]` (which has the same type).